# OpenTelemetry autoinstrumentation. Error with export spans via OTel collector to Jaeger

Tags: java, open-telemetry

I have a simple spring boot app and am trying to learn how to export spans with opentelemetry-javaagent via OpenTelemetry Collector in Jaeger. But I'm getting an error. My application provides a simple post Rest API.

Could you help me please what am I doing wrong?

```
Error
[opentelemetry.auto.trace 2022-03-15 10:02:28:286 +0000] [BatchSpanProcessor_ExporterThread_1] WARN io.opentelemetry.exporters.otlp.OtlpGrpcSpanExporter - Failed to export spans
SpringBootRestService_1  | io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNAVAILABLE: io exception
SpringBootRestService_1  |      at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.toStatusRuntimeException(ClientCalls.java:244)
SpringBootRestService_1  |      at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.getUnchecked(ClientCalls.java:225)
SpringBootRestService_1  |      at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.blockingUnaryCall(ClientCalls.java:142)
SpringBootRestService_1  |      at io.opentelemetry.proto.collector.trace.v1.TraceServiceGrpc$TraceServiceBlockingStub.export(TraceServiceGrpc.java:201)
SpringBootRestService_1  |      at io.opentelemetry.exporters.otlp.OtlpGrpcSpanExporter.export(OtlpGrpcSpanExporter.java:114)
SpringBootRestService_1  |      at io.opentelemetry.sdk.trace.export.BatchSpanProcessor$Worker$1.run(BatchSpanProcessor.java:288)
SpringBootRestService_1  |      at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
SpringBootRestService_1  |      at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
SpringBootRestService_1  |      at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
SpringBootRestService_1  |      at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
SpringBootRestService_1  |      at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
SpringBootRestService_1  | Caused by: io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: finishConnect(..) failed: Connection refused: localhost/127.0.0.1:55680
SpringBootRestService_1  | Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: finishConnect(..) failed: Connection refused
```

Configuration (otel-collector-config.yaml):

```
    receivers:
      otlp:
        protocols:
            grpc:
              endpoint:
    
    exporters:
      prometheus:
        endpoint: "0.0.0.0:8889"
        namespace: promexample
        const_labels:
          label1: value1
      logging:
        loglevel: debug
    
      zipkin:
        endpoint: http://zipkin-all-in-one:9411/api/v2/spans
        format: proto
    
      jaeger:
        endpoint: jaeger-all-in-one:14250
        insecure: true
    
    
    processors:
      batch:
    
    extensions:
      health_check:
      pprof:
        endpoint: :1888
      zpages:
        endpoint: :55679
    
    service:
      extensions: [pprof, zpages, health_check]
      pipelines:
        traces:
          receivers: [otlp]
          processors: [batch]
          exporters: [logging, zipkin, jaeger]
        metrics:
          receivers: [otlp]
          processors: [batch]
          exporters: [logging, prometheus]
    
    **docker-compose.yml**
    version: "3.8"
    
    services:
    
      SpringBootRestService:
        image: "spring-boot-rest-service"
        ports:
          - "8080-8090:8080-8090"
        volumes:
          - "./api/config/application.yml:/config/application.yml"
    
      # Jaeger
      jaeger-all-in-one:
        image: "jaegertracing/all-in-one:latest"
        ports:
          - 5775:5775/udp
          - 6831:6831/udp
          - 6832:6832/udp
          - 5778:5778
          - 16686:16686
          - 14268:14268
          - 14250:14250
    
      # Zipkin
      zipkin:
        image: openzipkin/zipkin:latest
        ports:
          - "9411:9411"
    
        # Collector
      otel-collector:
        image: ${OTELCOL_IMG}
        command: [ "--config=./config/otel-collector-config.yaml", "${OTELCOL_ARGS}" ]
        volumes:
          - ./otel-collector-config.yaml:/config/otel-collector-config.yaml
        ports:
          - "1888:1888"   # pprof extension
          - "8888:8888"   # Prometheus metrics exposed by the collector
          - "8889:8889"   # Prometheus exporter metrics
          - "13133:13133" # health_check extension
          - "55679:55679" # zpages extension
          - "55680:55680"
          - "4317:4317"   # otlp receiver grpc
          - "4318:4318"   # otlp receiver http
          - "55681:55681"
          - "6831:6831"
          - "6832:6832"
          - "9943:9943"
          - "1777:1777"
        depends_on:
          - jaeger-all-in-one
          - zipkin
```

Start:

```
    JAVA_OPTS="${JAVA_OPTS} \
      -Xms${JAVA_XMS} \
      -Xmx${JAVA_XMX} \
      -Dapplication.name=${APP_NAME} \
      -Dapplication.home=${APP_HOME} \
      -Dotel.traces.exporter=${OTEL_TRACES_EXPORTER} \
      -Dotel.service.name=${OTEL_SERVICE_NAME} \
      -Dotel.exporter.otlp.endpoint=${OTEL_EXPORTER_OTLP_ENDPOINT} \
      -javaagent:${APP_HOME}/opentelemetry-javaagent-all.jar"
    
    exec java ${JAVA_OPTS} \
      -jar "${APP_HOME}/${APP_NAME}.jar" \
      --spring.config.location=/config/application.yml
```

Environmental variables:

```
    OTEL_TRACES_EXPORTER=otlp
    OTELCOL_IMG=otel/opentelemetry-collector:latest
    OTELCOL_OPTIONS="--config=./config/otel-collector-config.yaml"
    OTEL_EXPORTER_OTLP_ENDPOINT=http://localhost:4317
    OTEL_EXPORTER_OTLP_TRACES_ENDPOINT=http://localhost:4317
    OTEL_EXPORTER_OTLP_TRACES_PROTOCOL=http/protobuf
    OTEL_SERVICE_NAME=spring-boot-rest-service
    OTEL_RESOURCE_ATTRIBUTES=application=APPLICATION_NAME
    OTELCOL_ARGS=
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `OTEL_EXPORTER_OTLP_TRACES_PROTOCOL` is set to `http/protobuf`; however your trace endpoint is set to `http://localhost:4317`, which is the default gRPC endpoint for the Collector. It should either be:

```
OTEL_EXPORTER_OTLP_TRACES_PROTOCOL=grpc
OTEL_EXPORTER_OTLP_TRACES_ENDPOINT=http://localhost:4317
```

or

```
OTEL_EXPORTER_OTLP_TRACES_PROTOCOL=http/protobuf
OTEL_EXPORTER_OTLP_TRACES_ENDPOINT=http://localhost:4318/v1/traces
```

See docs [here](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java/blob/main/sdk-extensions/autoconfigure/README.md#exporters)

Answer (score 0):

As per the logs it is trying to export to localhost:55680 which refers to your  application's container ,instead it should export to otel-collector's ip address.